# Modify request header going into a controller and response header leaving a Spring Boot RestController

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, spring-restcontroller

This feels like it should be a simple thing, but I'm still pretty new to SpringBoot, and the whole Servlet ecosystem, so it's not readily apparent. I would love an interface similar to HandlerInterceptor that allows me to modify the request and response object once I'm done in a controller. Even better would be to decorate mapping annotation, so I can specify which controllers need the operation.

The problem I'm solving right now, though I anticipate expanding this in the future, is that I have an encrypted header coming into my application that I would like to decrypt for use in the controller and then encrypt again on the way out.

EDIT: For clarity.

I have a rest controller, something like:

```
    @RestController
        public class PojoService {
            @GetMapping(value = "/path/to/resource")
                public ResponseEntity<SomeClass> getLocationData(
@RequestHeader(value = "EncryptedHeader", required = false) String ecryptedHeaderValue) {
                    DecryptionObject decryptedHeader = new DecryptionObject(pageHeaderValue);
                    SomePojo result = getResult();
                    return decryptedHeader.decorateResponseWithEncryptedHeader(result);
                }
    }
```

I would love to not have the DecryptionObject on every mapping, but rather, before I even get to the mapping, I decrypt the header via some filter or hook and then re-encrypt the header on the way out. Then my code would look something like:

```
    @RestController
        public class PojoService {
            @GetMapping(value = "/path/to/resource", decryptHeader="EncryptedHeader")
                public ResponseEntity<SomeClass> getLocationData(
@RequestHeader(value = "EncryptedHeader", required = false) String decryptedHeaderValue) {
                    SomePojo result = getResult();
                    return result;
                }
    }
```

I found that the HandlerInterceptor doesn't work because I cannot modify the request or response in the interceptor. Hope that clarifies the issue.

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use HandlerInterceptor. Create your class implementing HandlerInterceptor, and then register it using another class which extends [WebMvcConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#addInterceptors-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry-).

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class MyWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
         registry.addInterceptor(new [...]); //Apply to all controllers
         registry.addInterceptor(new [...]).addPathPatterns("path1","path2"); //Apply to specific paths to restrict to some controllers.
    }
}
```

You also could do it using a Filter - create your Filter class and register it by declaring a `@Bean` of type FilterRegistrationBean - this also allows you to restrict to some paths.

UPDATE: You could do this with request attributes which can be set by interceptors (`request.setAttribute("decryptedHeaderValue",<decrypted>)`. Or if you're specific about using headers, a filter would be more suitable for your purpose. Create a new wrapped request type that wraps the incoming request and does whatever you want, and pass this wrapper to the next filter in chain.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    [...]
    HttpServletRequestWrapper decryptedRequest = new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
       public String getHeader(String name) {
            if (name.equals("DecryptedHeader")) {
                  String encrypted = super.getHeader("EncryptedHeader");
                  String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted);
                  return decrypted;
            }
            return super.getHeader(name); //Default behavior
       }
   }

   
   chain.doFilter(decryptedRequest, response); //Pass on the custom request down
}
```

Then any class down the line (other filters, controllers etc) can just call `request.getHeader("DecryptedHeader")` to retrieve the decrypted header. This is just one of many similar approaches. You can restrict the paths for which this filter executes when registering it.

For response, there is a similar class HttpServletResponseWrapper which you can use for customization.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have attempted to sue the HandlerInterceptor, so I'm familiar with the syntax you posted, the request and response are immutable in an interceptor and I need to change header values.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this via addingAttribute in the `interceptor`

httpServletRequest.setAttribute(,);